# Get nested list using spring boot from Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to query MongoDB for Just idProfil and hashtags list from profileTwitter and bellow is the object:

```
{
"idProfil": "5ded2abae1692808b799b239",
"tweets": [
  {
    "idTweet": "5ded2dffe1692808b799b241",
    "datePublication": "2019-12-08T16:58:59.702+0000",
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "idHashtag": "5ded2c64e1692808b799b23c",
        "label": "recipes "
      },
      {
        "idHashtag": "5ded2c71e1692808b799b23d",
        "label": "delicious "
      },
      {
        "idHashtag": "5ded2c7ce1692808b799b23e",
        "label": "foodrecipes"
      },
      {
        "idHashtag": "5ded2c84e1692808b799b23f",
        "label": "canada "
      },
      {
        "idHashtag": "5ded2c8de1692808b799b240",
        "label": "Usa"
      },
      {
        "idHashtag": "5dee65d7e39e962d44a31c40",
        "label": "food"
      },
      {
        "idHashtag": "5dee65c8e39e962d44a31c3f",
        "label": "cooking"
      }
    ]
  }
 }
```

So my question is how to do this using spring boot ?

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried.

Comment: i don't tried any solution i can't understand them !

Comment: To get the nested list you need to use the spring data MongoDB aggregation framework. In that, you can add pipeline stage like match and projection.

Comment: @AshishBakwad can you give me an example based on data that i published in this post !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example based on data you have provided. Your question is not clear. Can you please provide more details on it.

```
List<AggregationOperation> stages = new ArrayList<>();

ProjectOperation projectOperation = project("idProfil").and("$tweets.hashtags").as("hashtags");

stages.add(projectOperation);

AggregationResults<ResultDTO> result = mongoOperation.aggregate(newAggregation(stages),
        "profileTwitter", ResultDTO.class);


public class ResultDTO {

   private String idProfil;

   private List<HashtagDTO>  hashtags;

   //getter setter

}

public class HashtagDTO {

   private String idHashtag;

   private String label;

   //getter setter

}
```